# python networkx remove nodes and edges with some condition

Tags: python, set, conditional-statements, networkx

In the python library networkx I would like to remove the nodes and edges of a graph which have some property. For example, suppose I wanted to remove all nodes and edges where the degree of a node was < 2. Consider the following psuedocode:

```
vdict = g.degree_dict()         #dictionary of nodes and their degrees
g.remove_from_nodes(v in g s.t. vdict[v] < 2)
```

I have seen some syntax that uses set theory notation but as I am still new to python I do not know how to use it. How do I convert this into working python code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we have an initialized graph `g` the following will set `f` to be `g` subject to the constraint that each vertex must have a degree > 0. We could easily generalize 0 with a variable:

```
f = nx.Graph()                                                                                                                                     
fedges = filter(lambda x: g.degree()[x[0]] > 0 and g.degree()[x[1]] > 0, g.edges())
f.add_edges_from(fedges)
```

Answer (score 33):

The Graph.remove_nodes_from() method takes a list (container actually) of nodes. So you just need to create a list that satisfies your condition.  You can use Python's [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) structure to compactly create a list of nodes to delete.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edge(1,2)

In [4]: G.add_edge(1,3)

In [5]: G.add_edge(1,4)

In [6]: G.add_edge(2,3)

In [7]: G.add_edge(2,4)

In [8]: G.degree()
Out[8]: {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 2}

In [9]: remove = [node for node,degree in dict(G.degree()).items() if degree > 2]

In [10]: remove
Out[10]: [1, 2]

In [11]: G.nodes()
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [12]: G.remove_nodes_from(remove)

In [13]: G.nodes()
Out[13]: [3, 4]
```

Comment: Could you please add a small explanation of the set theory language where you initialize `remove` since I have not used this language construct before?

Comment: Thanks, I needed to know the proper term.

Comment: You can inline lines 9 and 12 like so, with a similar comprehension:

`G.remove_nodes_from(node for node, degree in G.degree().items() if degree > 2)`

Comment: But be careful inlining like that if you are modifying the data structure (G) as you are inspecting it (G.degree().items()).

Comment: I get an "AttributeError: 'DegreeView' object has no attribute 'items'" error in line 9.

Comment: @schande, I edited the answer with a working version.

Comment: @Aric, Indeed! G is mutated even inside a function: you could make a deep copy to go around this problem: `import copy` and `G_copy = copy.deepcopy(G)`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in Aric's for networkx==2.2, you need to wrap `G.degree()` in a dictionary because the networkx view object doesn't have an items method. This line would be:

```
[node for node,degree in dict(G.degree()).items() if degree > 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

As of networkx==2.6, you can use this for graph `G`:

```
remove = [node for node, degree in G.degree() if degree < 2]
G.remove_nodes_from(remove)
```