# How to create edges in a network conditionally (using python Networkx package) based on other edges between nodes?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a dataset that shows parent-child relationship but no child-child relationship for siblings. I'm building a network using python's Networkx package (python version 3.6). I would like to add edges between siblings (if children share parents, they are siblings). How can I do this?

I've found some questions about conditional edge creation but in these questions the condition does not depend on other node properties (for example, existing edges to certain nodes):

[python networkx remove nodes and edges with some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261587/python-networkx-remove-nodes-and-edges-with-some-condition)

But I'm not sure how to formulate the condition in my case, to achieve what I want.

```
import networkx as nx

dat = {'child':[1,1,4,4,5,5,8,8], 'parent':[2,3,2,3,6,7,6,7]} 

# Create DataFrame 
data = pd.DataFrame(dat) 

# Create graph with known connections
G = nx.Graph()

def create_edges(row):
    return G.add_edge(row['child'],row['parent'])

data.apply(create_edges, axis=1)
```

I would like to create edge between nodes 1 and 4, and nodes 5 and 8 (because they share parents and are clearly siblings) but not between 1 and 5, or 4 and 8.

Comment: So the final network should just have childs as nodes or also parents?

Comment: Thanks, Yatu. I should have been more clear, I'm sorry. To answer your question: It should have both—nodes wouldn't change, I just need to add edges between the siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm not overcomplicating things, but this is how I'd go:

First, group the children by joint parents. The resulting variable `parents_children` is a `dict` with parents as keys and the set of every parent's children as values.

```
parents_children = {parent: {child for child in dat['child'] 
                         if (parent,child) in list(zip(dat['parent'],dat['child']))} 
                for parent in dat['parent']}
```

Afterwards, go over pairs of children with the same parent, and add an edge between them:

```
from itertools import combinations
for children in parents_children.values():
    for children_couple in combinations(children,2):
        G.add_edge(*children_couple)
```

I ran it on my side and I think it got the right result.

Comment: Thank you, Itamar. It's just what I needed. I appreciate your help.