# Remove all nodes that has a particular attribute in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I`m trying to remove all nodes within a Graph that has an specific attribute value.

I have seen this: [python networkx remove nodes and edges with some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261587/python-networkx-remove-nodes-and-edges-with-some-condition)

But in that case the degree is a property and not an attribute.

My graph has an attribute call "Line" which could have different values like: A, B, C.

So for example I want to remove all nodes with attribute "Line" equal to A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter nodes in your graph with a subgraph view:

```py
filter_node = lambda node: G.nodes[node]['Line'] == 'A'
filtered_nodes = list(nx.subgraph_view(G, filter_node=filter_node).nodes)
```

You can then remove these nodes from the graph:

```py
G.remove_nodes_from(e)
```